# Add row stored procedure not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a stored procedure to add a film to a database. I have got the stored procedure to 'getAllFilms' to work however when I run the addFilm, it comes up with an error: 'Not Found'

In mySQL, the stored procedure works:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sherattd`@`%` PROCEDURE `addFilm`(in Title varchar(45), in 
    Year int, in Director varchar(45), in Stars varchar(45), in Review 
    varchar(45))
BEGIN
    insert into films (title, year, director, stars, review) values (Title, 
    Year, Director, Stars, Review);
END
```

When I call it on visual studio, it errors:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var config = require('config');
var http = require("http");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var request 
//Add Film
router.post('/api/addFilm/:title/:year/:director/:stars/:review', function (req, res) {
console.log("hello");

var Title = req.params['title'];
var Year = req.params['year'];
var Director = req.params['director'];
var Stars = req.params['stars'];
var Review = req.params['review'];

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.get('EPAssignment.database.host'),
    user: config.get('EPAssignment.database.user'),
    password: config.get('EPAssignment.database.password'),
    database: config.get('EPAssignment.database.database')
});
console.log("hello x2");

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("CALL addFilm('" + Title + "', '" + Year + "', '" + Director + "', '" + Stars + "', '" + Review + "');", function (err, result, fields) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        console.log("hello x3");
        res.send(result[0]);
    });
});

});= require('request');
```

When I call it, using the test values of (Test, 2000, Test, Test, Test), the console logs:

```
App GET [404] /api/addFilm/Test/2000/Test/Test/Test
```

Thanks

Comment: Mysql and SQL-Server are different things.  The SQL-Server tag refers to Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: It does not look like a DB error. Could you check that you are using the correct rest calls ?? 
If you see in the code you have a post. But in the error that you are showing us you have a GET.